# How to troubleshoot Google Cloud MySQL connectivity Issues?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, typeorm

I'm struggling to connect to my database instance from a google cloud function. using my rest client I get the error:

> Error: connect ENOENT /cloudsql/my-project:us-central1:my-data-lake at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) -------------------- at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/me/Code/dietstats/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48) at Protocol.handshake (/Users/me/Code/dietstats/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23) at PoolConnection.connect (/Users/me/Code/dietstats/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18) at Pool.getConnection (/Users/me/Code/dietstats/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16) at /Users/me/Code/dietstats/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:863:18 at new Promise () at MysqlDriver.createPool (/Users/me/Code/dietstats/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:860:16) at MysqlDriver. (/Users/me/Code/dietstats/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:288:51) at step (/Users/me/Code/dietstats/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:143:27) at Object.next (/Users/me/Code/dietstats/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:124:57)

In my cloud logger, I only see the following messages when I try to connect:

> "2022-01-05T16:56:21.312241Z 44943 [Warning] User 'mysql.session'@'localhost' was assigned access 0x8000 but was allowed to have only 0x0."

> "2022-01-05T16:56:21.312200Z 44943 [Warning] entry 'root'@'localhost' in mysql.user is ignored because it duplicates entry in mysql.system_user"

This is funny because I'm not even connecting using these users.

**So with such enigmatic messages, how can I troubleshoot my connection?**

Comment: Can you connect using mysql client from a VM? How did you set up connectivity on the Cloud SQL instance? Private IP? Public IP? Take Cloud Functions out of the mix first to be sure you can reach your instance at all.

Comment: While waiting for the information requested in the comments above, take a look to following documentation that might help you: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/error-messages, https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/diagnose-issues.

Comment: @GabeWeiss For DX review, see my answer below. I have things working locally and in gCloud, but I was struggling because I was unaware of cloud function-level permissions and how those come into effect with connecting to other Google services.

Answer (score 1):

I had several conceptual hurdles to overcome.

1. Permissions: There are user permissions for the database, cloud functions, and the iAm roles. I was hung up with the permissions for the cloud functions specifically and I was able to make it work by giving "All User" complete access. This is not secure, but it's working. I'm still not sure how to connect the correct service account for the cloud functions to requests to the database. Any suggestions would be helpful.
2. Prod vs Dev (emulator). I now recall that access is less strict within the google ecosystem, so running my functions on my emulator was a bad idea for troubleshooting. There are ways (such as SSL or VM) but I could figure those out. Ultimately, I had to deploy every time.
3. ORM: I'm using typeorm for the first time and many of the tutorials are outdated.

The convergence of these new challenges made it difficult to troubleshoot anyo ne of them.

Comment: To be specific, is it trouble CALLING the Cloud Function? Or is it a problem calling FROM the Cloud Function to the database? When you say "All User" complete access, what specifically are you setting that on?

Comment: Calling FROM the Cloud Function to the database. the "All Users" permission was associated with the cloud function, not the database

Comment: Gotcha, so when you say "Giving All User complete access" do you mean opening up the database wide? How did you do that? Something on the Cloud SQL side, or the Cloud Run side? In theory, all you should have to do in order to get access is to set the service account that the Cloud Run instance uses to one that has the Cloud SQL Client role. By default, Cloud Run uses the default Compute Engine service account, which doesn't have that role. So either, you can grant the Compute service account that Cloud SQL role, or use a different service account (recommended) to assign to the Cloud Run.

Comment: This all depends on how the Cloud SQL instance it set up as well of course. If you're set to Private IP connectivity only on the Cloud SQL instance, then you'll ALSO have to set up a Serverless VPC Connector, and associate it with the Cloud Run (can set it in a dropdown on edit and deploy new revision section).

Comment: From this interface:
https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/details/us-central1/funcName?project=projectName&tab=permissions

principal="All Users" role="Cloud Functions Invoker"

Comment: What service account does it say is being used on the Cloud Run instance? Look at the Cloud Run instance in console, click on Revisions tab, then on the right hand side, click on the Security tab. Is the service account listed there the default compute engine service account?